# Implement ospf routing

Tags: routing, cisco-asa, ospf

My topology is
---**rtr1**-.1---192.168.10.0/24....2.**asa1**-.2---1.1.1.0/24----.1-**asa2**-.1---192.168.20.0/24---.2-**rtr2**

My goal is rtr2 can reach rtr1 via OSPF routing and vice versa
my problem is on ASA, I am already configuring ip address correctly, it can ping each other, and then inserting command on every router

```
router ospf 1
network [connected_network] area 0
```

I am also already inserting ACL on every ASA

```
access-list OUTSIDE extended permit icmp any any 
access-list OUTSIDE extended permit ospf any any 
access-group OUTSIDE in interface outside
```

the result show ip route in ASA2 still like below:

```
C        192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0 is directly connected, inside
L        192.168.20.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, inside
C        1.1.1.1.0 255.255.255.0 is directly connected, outside
L        1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, outside
```

any command I should insert in ASA, is there a missing command?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post both ASA complete configuration and software version?

Comment: Have you configured OSPF so that any interfaces are included in the OSPF process? You should give us your complete configuration for your ASAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot establish OSPF neighborship between non directly connected neighbors (unless you're using a L2 tunnel).
OSPF uses 224.0.0.5/6 for it's communication. Multicast addresses in the range of 224.0.0.x have TTL=1.
So once this packet reaches ASA it is simply dropped.

Comment: As I understand the question, OP try to configure OSPF between the two ASA which are directly connected.

Comment: Yes I think you are right, so the issue is simply establishing OSPF neighborship between rtr and ASA.